# Unable to enumerate USB device

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, scanner

I have an old Acer S2W 3300 U scanner that I used to use in Linux some ten years ago.  Tried to install it in an updated Slackware64 linux box, but the kernel doesn't seem to be able to identify it.

```
 # uname -a                                                                          
Linux leao 4.4.38 #2 SMP Sun Dec 11 16:11:02 CST 2016 x86_64 Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1246 v3 @ 3.50GHz GenuineIntel GNU/Linux


# grep -v '^#' /etc/sane.d/snapscan.conf | head  -6                                 

firmware /usr/share/sane/snapscan/u176v046.bin
/dev/usb/scanner0 bus=usb



# ls -l /usr/share/sane/snapscan/u176v046.bin                                       
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lupe lupe 31385 nov 12 00:44 /usr/share/sane/snapscan/u176v046.bin

# dmesg | tail

[  452.508560] usb 1-13: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
[  452.508563] usb 1-13: can't read configurations, error -110
[  452.661561] usb 1-13: new full-speed USB device number 12 using xhci_hcd
[  457.825481] usb 1-13: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
[  457.825484] usb 1-13: can't read configurations, error -110
[  457.978466] usb 1-13: new full-speed USB device number 13 using xhci_hcd
[  462.990385] usb 1-13: unable to read config index 0 descriptor/start: -110
[  462.990389] usb 1-13: can't read configurations, error -110
[  463.143374] usb 1-13: new full-speed USB device number 14 using xhci_hcd
```

Can I have any hope to make this work?

Comment: Looks like a hardware problem in the scanner / USB connection. Did you try a different cable (on the low chance it's the cable)?

Comment: @dirkt: It's not the cable. Thank you for your interest!